# how to remove compare products from FEATURED product in opencart from manually

Tags: compare, opencart

hello friends plz help me out 
i try so many modules to hide /remove the add to compare and add to wishlist from my website. i am unable to locate the file plz help me out so that i can manually remove the code in the files

i use this module 
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=10311

But not up to the mark

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hi you look for this block of code in every module and page you don't want it showing on and either comment it out or delete it

```
    <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_wishlist; ?>" onclick="wishlist.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
    <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_compare; ?>" onclick="compare.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
```